# Reading / Writing security properties to objects in Active Directory (the same way Delegation of rights work) C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-security

I'm looking for a way to read and set security permissions on an object (OU or users/computers) in Active Directory on Windows Server 2008+. The same way that Delegation by using Active Directory Wizard does it? I would like to be able to choose OU and assign group to it with Reset Password permissions or with ability to create / manage users?

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a simple example that allow the domain user '`user1`' to reset password for users presents in OU '`ForUser1`'

```
/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
DirectoryEntry workingOU = new DirectoryEntry();
workingOU.Options.SecurityMasks = SecurityMasks.Owner | SecurityMasks.Group | SecurityMasks.Dacl | SecurityMasks.Sacl;
workingOU.Path = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/ou=ForUser1,dc=dom,dc=fr";

/* Retreive Obect security
 */
ActiveDirectorySecurity adsOUSec = workingOU.ObjectSecurity;

/* Ellaborate the user to delegate
 */
NTAccount ntaToDelegate = new NTAccount("dom", "user1");
SecurityIdentifier sidToDelegate = (SecurityIdentifier)ntaToDelegate.Translate (typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

/* Specils Guids
 */
Guid UserForceChangePassword = new Guid("00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529");
Guid userSchemaGuid = new Guid("BF967ABA-0DE6-11D0-A285-00AA003049E2");
Guid pwdLastSetSchemaGuid = new Guid("bf967a0a-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2");

/* Ellaborate ACEs
 */
ExtendedRightAccessRule erarResetPwd = new ExtendedRightAccessRule(ntaToDelegate, AccessControlType.Allow, UserForceChangePassword, ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.Descendents, userSchemaGuid);
PropertyAccessRule parPwdLastSetW = new PropertyAccessRule(ntaToDelegate, AccessControlType.Allow, PropertyAccess.Write, pwdLastSetSchemaGuid, ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.Descendents, userSchemaGuid);
PropertyAccessRule parPwdLastSetR = new PropertyAccessRule(ntaToDelegate, AccessControlType.Allow, PropertyAccess.Read, pwdLastSetSchemaGuid, ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance.Descendents, userSchemaGuid);
adsOUSec.AddAccessRule(erarResetPwd);
adsOUSec.AddAccessRule(parPwdLastSetW);
adsOUSec.AddAccessRule(parPwdLastSetR);

workingOU.CommitChanges();
```

After that you need :

a [place to find ExtendedRightAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

a place to find Active-Directory schema [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) informations.

Comment: I'll check how it goes but it seems to be exactly what I need. I guess I can extend on ObjectSecurity when reading the information? So I can find out what groups and what "rights" are assigned to that OU?