# Setting ACL on Exchange Mailbox

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I'm trying to add a group to a mailbox (in C#). I'm using a mix of CDOEXM, DirectoryServices.AccountManagement calls, and failing. This is my code:

```
// userDe is a DirectoryEntry
IExchangeMailbox exMb = (IExchangeMailbox)userDe.NativeObject;
IADsSecurityDescriptor securityDescriptor = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)exMb.MailboxRights;
IADsAccessControlList acl = (IADsAccessControlList)securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl;
AccessControlEntry ace = new AccessControlEntry();

// groupName - I have successfully created the group earlier
ace.Trustee = groupName;
acl.AddAce(ace);
securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl = acl;
exMb.MailboxRights = securityDescriptor;

// How do I save it?
exMb.CommitChanges() etc etc
...or userDe.Properties["ntSecurityDescriptor"] = securityDescriptor;
```

Not sure what to do next, everything I try results in a compilation error or a InvalidCastException.

Please help

Comment: In which line does it fail with a compilation error? Where is the InvalidCastException being thrown?

Comment: I made an answer to a similar question [Reading / Writing security properties to objects in Active Directory (the same way Delegation of rights work) C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6251126/608772).

Comment: Henning, I was getting various errors depending on which variation of the code I used. I've experimented with a few now. I think some good examples are what I need and couldn't find many earlier (especially the CDOEXM stuff). However, JPBlanc, thanks I took a look at your example and I think I understand a bit more now, so I'll try out a few things based on your examples when I get into work tomorrow. If either of you can point me at some good docs for this that would be an extra bonus. Thanks both of you for replying, appreciated.

Comment: I think what I need to do, once I have got the security descriptor updated, is set the user's "msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor" but if I do user.Properties["msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor"] = ... I get told it's a readonly property. Help...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after quite a bit of pain (the integer values I am setting somehow correspond to enum values in the API but I couldn't get them to work). The variable userDe is a DirectoryEntry.

```
            IExchangeMailbox exMb = (IExchangeMailbox)userDe.NativeObject;
            IADsSecurityDescriptor securityDescriptor = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)exMb.MailboxRights;
            IADsAccessControlList acl = (IADsAccessControlList)securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl;
            AccessControlEntry ace = new AccessControlEntry();
            ace.Trustee = groupName;
            ace.AccessMask = 1;
            ace.AceFlags = 2;
            ace.AceType = 0;

            acl.AddAce(ace);
            securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl = acl;
            IADsUser iadsUser = (IADsUser)userDe.NativeObject;
            iadsUser.Put("msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor", securityDescriptor);

            iadsUser.SetInfo();
```